# Flutter Loading Widget class Color

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

once again im back here again as im new coding using flutter and im learning as i experiment.
What i want to do is make a global loading widget that can be called to display the loading widget with a specified color and was wondering if anyone can assist me acomplish this.

For example...

How i would prefer to call the Loading Widget:

```
LoadingWidget(Orange);
```

`global_widgets.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/res/colors.dart';

class LoadingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
        // Replace following with specified Color like, CustomColors.'specifield_color'??
        // CustomColors.[replace with specified color]
        CustomColors.Orange,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/logo.png',
          height: 20,
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8),
        Text(
          'My',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColors.Navy,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'App',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColors.Orange,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`colors.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomColors {
  static final Color Navy = Color(0xFF2C384A);
  static final Color Orange = Color(0xFFF57C00);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the variable `customColor` of the type `Color` to `LoadingWidget`

```
class LoadingWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final Color customColor;
  LoadingWidget(this.customColor);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
        customColor, // <--- // your specified color
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can call the widget like this : `LoadingWidget(CustomColors.Orange)`

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/nerdpepe/4d7b6ca79a19e663f2190167900b0ed1) contains the working code and you can run it on DartPad if you need.